# Robots.txt how to crawl specific type of urls while excluding others similar

Tags: html, seo, robots.txt, google-crawlers

I have these types of URL's :

```
www.example.com/view/a-dF%2Dg3_dG
www.example.com/view/a-K5gD2%3F%f
www.example.com/view/a-b3R%2f%s_2
```

So basically they start with `/view/a-` and continue with randum chars. I want to block google from crawling them.

However, there is one exception. I have an URL which looks like this:

```
www.example.com/view/a-home
```

This should be an exception, this URL should still be crawled. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work for all bots, but the major search engines now support both `Disallow` and `Allow` directives:

```bash
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /a-
Allow: /a-home
```

The longest matching rule is the one that gets used.  For `/a-home` both rules match, but the rule that allows it it longer, so it is used.  For `/a-dFte`, only the disallow rule matches.

Bots that don't understand `Allow:` directives would be unable to crawl your home page.

You can use [Google's robots.txt tester tool](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062598?hl=en) to make sure that your robots.txt syntax is correct and that specific URLs are either disallowed or allowed as you expect.

Comment: My first thought was to Disalow: /view/a-* , no ? Is there a difference between /a- and /view/a-* ?

Comment: What do you mean by longer ?

Comment: robots.txt accept regex ? Can't we disalow only those type of urls exluding the home page from the same condition ? So have only disallow but only on those pages ? In order to work for all bots ?

Comment: `robots.txt` does not support regular expressions. Some crawlers support globs with `*`, but there is no need to use that here because  robots that text rules are all "starts with" rules.  There is an implied `*` at then end of every single rule.  It is better to avoid using globs when possible because most robots don't support those and then won't understand the rule.

Comment: Longer rule means more characters in the rule itself. The `/a-`  has three characters and the `/a-home` has seven, so it is the longer rule.